I'm using NEXTUI Modal. When I click on <Button onPress={onOpen}> Its calling all Modals
Blog has max-w and overflow so it can't show full text. I used NextUI's Modal so I can see the full post.
const TaskM = () => {

const { myapp, handleRemoveTodo, desc, handleAddTodo, blog,tyPe,task } = useContext(Context);
const { isOpen, onOpen, onOpenChange } = useDisclosure();
const [scrollBehavior, setScrollBehavior] = React.useState("inside");
const [modalPlacement, setModalPlacement] = React.useState("center");
const modal =(_index: any)=>{
    document.getElementById("hello")
}

return (

    <div className='flex flex-col justify-center w-full items-start '>
        <ul className="todo-list items-center flex flex-col gap-5 w-full h-auto justify-center ">
            {(myapp || [])?.map((blog: any, index: number) => {
                if (blog.type === "Backlog") {
                    return <>
                        <Button onPress={onOpen}
                            key={index} className='bg-white min-h-[100px] h-auto rounded-2xl flex shadow-lg shadow-gray-300 md:break-words flex-col w-[90%] justify-start gap-4 items-center'>
                            <div className='flex flex-row mt-2 justify-between w-[90%] '>
                                <h1 className='text-black w-[90%] '>
                                    <li className={`block text-gray-700 md:break-words w-[90%] mb-3  flex-row text-xs justify-between items-center rounded-lg  `} id={blog.title} key={index}>
                                        {blog.title}
                                        {/* {JSON.stringify(_cards)} */}
                                    </li>
                                </h1>
                                <button className="  text-gray-300  items-center flex justify-center   w-[10%] h-[20px] " onClick={() => handleRemoveTodo(index)}>
                                    <BsThreeDots />
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div className='w-full h-auto flex flex-col justify-start items-center rounded-none'>
                                <li className=' text-gray-700 h-auto max-h-[160px] max-w-[90%] text-wrap capitalize  overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden break-all w-[90%] mb-3 flex flex-row text-xs justify-start items-start rounded-lg' id={blog.desc} key={index}>
                                    {blog.desc}
                                </li>
                            </div>


                        </Button>

                        <Modal
                            isOpen={isOpen}
                            onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
                            scrollBehavior={scrollBehavior}
                            placplacement={modalPlacement}
                            key={index}
                            id ='hello'
                        >
                            <ModalContent 


                            >
                                {(onClose) => (
                                    <>

                                        <div className='bg-white min-h-[100px] h-auto rounded-2xl text-black flex shadow-lg shadow-gray-300 md:break-words flex-col w-full justify-start gap-4 items-center'>
                                            <ModalHeader className="flex flex-col gap-1 ">
                                                {blog.type}
                                            </ModalHeader>
                                            <h1 className='text-black w-[90%] '>
                                                <li className={`block text-gray-700 md:break-words w-[90%] mb-3  flex-row text-xs justify-between items-center rounded-lg  `} id={blog.title} key={index}>
                                                    {blog.title}
                                                    {/* {JSON.stringify(_cards)} */}
                                                </li>
                                            </h1>
                                            <ModalBody className='flex justify-start items-start w-full'>


                                                
                                                <div className='w-full h-auto flex flex-col justify-start items-start rounded-none'>
                                                    <li className=' text-gray-700 h-auto max-h-[210px] max-w-[90%] text-wrap capitalize break-all w-[90%] mb-3 flex flex-row text-xs justify-start items-start rounded-lg' id={blog.desc} key={index}>
                                                        {blog.desc}
                                                    </li>
                                                </div>

                                            </ModalBody>
                                            <ModalFooter>
                                                <Button
                                                    color="danger"
                                                    variant="light"
                                                    onPress={onClose}
                                                    className="p-2  rounded-2xl w-auto bg-blue-500 text-white border-0 outline-none hover:bg-blue-400 "
                                                >
                                                    Close
                                                </Button>

                                            </ModalFooter>
                                        </div>

                                    </>
                                )}
                            </ModalContent>
                        </Modal>
                    </>;
                }
            }
            )}

        </ul>
    </div>
)


}

export default TaskM

THIS component is for post my blog. When I click on the posted blog , onpress={onOpen} calling every modals of every blog at the same time. I copied this modal code from NextUI Modal. So I don't know what to do and how to fix it. I think I should give id on every blogs but I don't know how to do it. Because every blogs are posted from 1 component.

So basically you want to show blog details in a Modal when clicked on blog name (title) ?
